# TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter

I was trying out Twitter API but it give me this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "D:/MAGIC/python/twitterdemo.pu.py", line 23, in 
>      text += status.text.encode('utf-8')
>   TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly

Here is my code:

```
import sys
import operator
import requests
import json
import twitter
from watson_developer_cloud import PersonalityInsightsV2 as PersonalityInsights

twitter_consumer_key = ''  
twitter_consumer_secret = ''  
twitter_access_token = ''  
twitter_access_secret = ''

twitter_api = twitter.Api(consumer_key=twitter_consumer_key, consumer_secret=twitter_consumer_secret, access_token_key=twitter_access_token, access_token_secret=twitter_access_secret)

handle = "@somethingsoemthing"
statuses = twitter_api.GetUserTimeline(screen_name=handle, count=200, include_rts=False)

text = ""

for status in statuses:
  print (status.text)
  if(status.lang == 'en'): #Enligh tweets
    text += status.text.encode('utf-8')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you encode it, it has been a `str` before and is now `bytes`, but you need a `str` here. So remove the `.encode('utf-b')` and try again.

Answer (score 3):

Your `text` is initialized as a `str`, and you're trying to add a `bytes` object (which is what `status.text.encode('utf-8')` returns) to it.  Initialize `text` as a `bytes` object and that error should go away:

```
text = b''
```

Alternatively, you could skip encoding the text altogether and it should work:

```
text += status.text
```